# google earth kml animatedupdate multiple changes

Tags: animation, model, kml

I cannot figure out how to apply multiple animatedupdate 'tour steps' in KML. Please help. All data is linked here to demonstrate the problem. In this example.. first open the link to the rail model - this has the snap shot that takes you (the user) to the project area. Zoom in on the northern most rail curve. Then open the other KMZ - named DOC02 ... DOC02 provides the animation (Tour) ... play the tour (part 2) and ... the hopper goes a short way around the curve, although the tour data has enough steps to almost complete the entire curve - Why are only the first 3 animated updates applied? ... At first I tried to use the guides referred to by countless other stack overflow posts on this topic. But that result was even worse. The 3d model has a location ID of t1 and an orientation ID of t2. When I use these as target ID in the animated updates - Yuck! the animation is totally incorrect, model goes directly to the end of the curve. So. I added ID's at every transform change. This idea provided better animation but the animation only uses the first 2 animated updates. If all this text just gives people a headache, just let me know and I will provide a video ... I probably will make one later today anyway. Thanks for your patience.

[overhead rail model in KMZ Google Earth](https://www.dropbox.com/s/slbaotc7jl7qndv/rail_model.kmz?dl=0)

[3d hopper model set go move around curve in KMZ Google Earth](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r5bawnw80lsjfz2/doc02.kmz?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/touring#gxanimatedupdate-and-the-tour-timeline

The above link will take you to the kml documentation page which specifically states that:

> "Animated updates run parallel to the timeline - that is, the tour continues directly to the next tour primitive in the playlist, while the animated update is taking place. The gx:duration controls the length of time it takes for the update to occur, but doesn't delay the next tour primitive. To allow an animated update to complete before the next action takes place, insert a gx:Wait, with a duration equal to the duration of the update, between the animated update and the following tour primitive. In addition, an animated update will be truncated if its duration extends beyond that of the last gx:FlyTo or gx:Wait element. You can either change the appropriate gx:duration values, or insert an additional gx:Wait element at the end of the playlist to give the animated update time to complete.

Which essentially is telling you that AnimatedUpdate will not keep the tour going. Only flyTo and Wait will prolong the tour. The reason why your tour ends after the first 2 animations is because that is all the animations it can get through within the tour length.

Basically, to fix your issue, insert a gx:wait with a duration >= your AnimatedUpdate's duration after **EACH** AnimatedUpdate. This will prolong the tour and allow your animations time to complete before the tour ends. (because the gx:wait prolongs the tour)

(Alternatively, add a long enough Wait at the beginning, much like you did with the end.)

Also see: https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/touring#tour-timelines